# Lotus Notes Java app can’t find notes.ini

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

Both the systems described are Windows XP with Lotus Notes 8.5.

I have a Java app (sample code below) that uses notes.jar to interact with Lotus Notes. The app works fine on a system that has `notes.ini` in the Lotus install dir of `c:\Program Files\Lotus\Notes` and the user ID file is in `c:\Program Files\Lotus\Notes\Data`. The user has to type a password to login to Lotus. This system has `HKLM\Software\Lotus\Notes\MultiUser` set to `0` (single user system). On this machine, the below code displays good values on the four `println`’s.

On a problem system, this app prints the four headings but blanks for the four values (the user name, key filename, mailfile, and mailserver are all blank). This problem system has `notes.ini` and the user ID file in `D:\Data\johnsmith\NotesData`. Lotus is installed in `C:\Program Files\Lotus\Notes`. This problem system also has `HKLM\Software\Lotus\Notes\MultiUser` set to `1` (implying it is multiuser instead of single user). Finally, under Lotus’s File -> Security -> User Security dialog the "Log in to Notes using your operating system login" box is checked (so the user doesn’t type in a password to login to Lotus).

So, it appears that on the problem system, the `notes.ini` file can’t be found (since `notes.ini` is where the four output values are supposed to be read from). I’ve looked through the `Notes.jar` API and can’t see any way to specify the location of `notes.ini`. The dir where `notes.ini` resides is in the Windows `PATH`, but that doesn’t help.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import lotus.domino.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try {
    NotesThread.sinitThread();
    Session session = NotesFactory.createSession();

    System.out.println("Common user name: " + session.getCommonUserName());
    System.out.println("KeyFilename: " + session.getEnvironmentString("KeyFilename", true));
    System.out.println("MailFile: " + session.getEnvironmentString("MailFile", true));
    System.out.println("MailServer: " + session.getEnvironmentString("MailServer", true));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    NotesThread.stermThread();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the original question, if `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Lotus\Notes\MultiUser` has a value of `1`, then you have a multi-user installation (even if you are the only user of Lotus).

Here is a solution that worked. Find the location of `Notes.ini`, probably somewhere like `C:\Documents and Settings\(username)\Lotus`. Edit or create the string value below and set it to your `Notes.ini` directory. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Lotus\Notes\(optional-version)\NotesIniPath`.

In a multi-user environment, Lotus Notes gets the `ini` filename from the `NotesIniPath` registry value.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new command-line parameter, "=c:\data\johnsmith\NotesData\notes.ini" .  To make this happen, you need to use NotesFactory.CreateSession(String host, String args[], String user, String passwd); method, after setting up a new String array containing that parameter and whatever other arguments were passed, since itis basically supposed to be the String args[] as passed to static Main.  (The =fullpath\notes.ini parameter just needs to be in the array, it doesn't need to be in any specific location.)

This permits the session to be initialized with the absolute path to the notes.ini file used, and appears to be supported since (though I could be wrong) Notes 5.0.5.

Notably, the Directory= line is going to be taken from that notes.ini and used for all error reporting and logging, as the user's private data directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of things you can try:

1. Notes actually comes with its own JVM and I found using this JVM makes Java applications run more reliably with Notes classes since any eventually needed support library would be properly configured.
2. What happens if notes is already running before you start your program. There are 2 variations here: Checkbox "Don't prompt for a password from other Notes-based programs" is checked or unchecked.
3. Make sure to switch to the directory where the `Notes.ini` is at home before you run the app. (And verify that the user can't see any other `notes.ini` variables)

Comment: Those were good suggestions. Unfortunately none of them worked.